# Setting an incrementing and resetting value for rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm adding a new `int` column to an existing table. I'm trying to set a value for all the rows in the table.

```
players_table:
 - id
 - company_id
 - rank // new column
```

To set the initial values for rank I want to just increment the rank by 1 grouped by company.

Example

```
companies:
id | name
---------------
1  | first comp
2  | second comp

players:
id | company_id | rank 
-----------------------
1  |     1      |   1
2  |     1      |   2
3  |     1      |   3
4  |     2      |   1
5  |     2      |   2
```

Is it possible to achieve this with SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select p.*, row_number() over (partition by p.company_id order by p.id) as rank
from players p;
```

To set the value, use `update`:

```
update players p
    set rank = new_rank
from (select p.*, row_number() over (partition by p.company_id order by p.id) as new_rank
      from players p
     ) pp
where pp.id = p.id;
```

Comment: I tried executing this query but I get this error `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "on"
LINE 6: on pp.id = p.id;`

Comment: @Rodrigo . . . That is now `where`.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` or `RANK` window function.

```
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY company_id order by id )rank
FROM players
```