# Calculate percentage two values and sum arithmetic operations mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is a very basic look at my table. I have columns 4.

```
| Product_Id       | TypePayment_Id      | Value        | Percent      |
| ---------------- |:-------------------:| ------:      | ------------:|
| 25               | 1                   |  30          |  50.00       |
| 26               | 1                   |  40          |  25.00       |
| 27               | 1                   |  50          |  25.00       |
| 28               | 2                   |  25          |  50.00       |
| 29               | 2                   |  30          |  25.00       |
| 30               | 3                   |  85          |  50.00       |
| 31               | 3                   |  90          |  25.00       |
| 32               | 3                   |  100         |  25.00       |
```

Need to generate this result:

```
| TypePayment_Id      | Total        | Comission    |
|:-------------------:| ------:      | ------------:|
| 1                   |  120         |  37.50       |
| 2                   |  55          |  20.00       |
| 3                   |  275         |  90.00       |
```

I need generate this result with a query in MYSQL, this is possible?

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server ? Both are different RDBMS

Comment: What is the logic behind calculating the commission ?

Comment: So what have you tried? You do know how to calculate percentages, I assume? And it's easy enough to find out how to use `SUM` in SQL. So what's the actual question here?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, total * percent.

Comment: Hint: GROUP BY and SUM().

Comment: Hey, it's a bit unfair to change the question when you've already got some fine answers...

Comment: I need to group as TypePayment_Id, edited example, look plis.

Comment: Although the answers below contradict this, in general SO tries not to play the role of a code writing service

Comment: @Strawberry humbly want to point out just couple of answers out of thousands, which seems like a code writing service, by contributors of very very high reputation:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52655195/2469308  and  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52655014/2469308 

OP had given valid **Minimal and Verifiable** dataset (no image), and **Complete and Expected** Output (no images). So, I felt that it is worth answering, as there has been some attempt in framing question, at OP's end.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- Use aggregation functions like [`SUM()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum).
- Do `Group By` on `TypePayment_Id`.
- Logically, you will need to calculate commission value **per row**; because commission percent **may vary**. Then, **SUM** them up to compute total commission paid for a `TypePayment_Id`.

Try **(for MySQL)**:

```
SELECT  
  `TypePayment_Id`, 
  SUM(`Value`) AS `Total`, 
  SUM(`Value` * `Percent` / 100) As `Commission`
FROM `your_table` 
GROUP BY 
  `TypePayment_Id`
```

Comment: Note that backticks are MySQL only. (And not needed for non-reserved words.)

Comment: I need to group as TypePayment_Id, edited example, look plis.

Comment: Does MySQL require backticks for TypePayment_Id?!? That's a valid identifier.

Comment: @jarlh does it cause any harm ? I personally believe that it is a good and safe practice to use backticks, to avoid inadvertent behaviour.

Comment: No harm at all - as long as you're writing for MySQL only.

Comment: @jarlh I have added a caveat in my answer for MySQL

Comment: Underscore is not an "alternative character" when it comes to identifiers (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html)

Comment: @jarlh not getting the context. Something wrong with the answer ? Please enlighten. Happy to fix it :)

Comment: @ÍtaloGustavo Please dont keep on editing this question to add more requirements; You need to mark this question as complete by accepting an answer (whichever worked for you best); and post a new question for your additional requirements.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, thanks, you can help for the last time?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, I got it ... Thank you!!

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, nothing wrong at all, I did even upvote! (I was just discussing identifiers, that backticks are valid but not needed here.)

Comment: @jarlh thanks. :-) everyday is a learning day for me at SO :-)

Answer (score -1):

Try this with aggregation

```
   select TypePayment_Id,sum(Value) as total, 
   (sum(Value)*max(Percent))/100.0 as commission
   from tablename
   group by TypePayment_Id
```

Comment: I need to group as TypePayment_Id, edited example, look plis.

Comment: remove product_id from group by and select list @ÍtaloGustavo